# How to filter an item from an array in state in React functional component (To Do List)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, react-state

This is my array where I add array object 
**const [task, setTask] = useState([]);**

```
export const productArray = [

  { 
    Name: "White Flowers",
    oldPrice: "$45.99",
    newPrice: "$35.99",
  },
  {
   Name: "Blue and Pink Jeans",
    oldPrice: "$57.99",
    newPrice: "$40.99",
  },
  {
    Name: "Yellow Tshirt",
    oldPrice: "$53.99",
    newPrice: "$37.99",
  },
  {
    Name: "Black Hoodie",
    oldPrice: "$40.99",
    newPrice: "$33.99",
  },
]
```

How do I filter this array of objects? I don't want to filter them by their attributes. I want to filter using their indexes.

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work?  It's not clear to me what you're asking or how this `productArray` is related to your `task` state.

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: array splice or slice is what you're looking for

Comment: productArray[0] would be the first item in the array; if you wanted an array with just that value then [productArray[0]]

Comment: Thanks for your response. But the problem is solved.